# C++ curl POST for LiFx Control

Tags: c++, curl, libcurl, lifx

I'm using curl with c++ to list all the bulbs successfully

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_USERNAME, MY_API_key);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.lifx.com/v1beta1/lights/all/");
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteCallback);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &Data);
res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
```

To toggle power to all light the documentation http://developer.lifx.com/#toggle-power says to use

```
curl -u "c87c73a896b554367fac61f71dd3656af8d93a525a4e87df5952c6078a89d192:" -X POST "https://api.lifx.com/v1beta1/lights/all/toggle"
```

I've tested this via the pre-built curl binary it works fine. I can't figure out how to construct the POST format in the C++ code.

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_USERNAME, MY_API_key);
curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_POST,"https://api.lifx.com/v1beta1/lights/all/toggle");
curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteCallback);
curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &Data);
res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
```

However, res returns CURLE_URL_MALFORMAT, I think this is because I haven't set the CURLOPT_URL property... but I'm not sure what it needs to be set to.

I tried using a similar format to this PHP question ([PHP HTTP CURL PUT request for LIFX Power On/Off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30284346/php-http-curl-put-request-for-lifx-power-on-off)) but with no luck, it still returns CURLE_URL_MALFORMAT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CURLOPT_POST](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_POST.html) is wrongly used there. It should be set to 0 or 1 only. You set the URL with [CURLOPT_URL](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_URL.html).

You could use `--libcurl sample.c` added to your (working) curl command line to get a good sample source code to start from.

To mimic that command line closer, you can probably skip CURLOPT_POST and just have [CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST.html) set to "POST"

Comment: Using CURLOPT_POST correctly resulted in the post being sent but it didn't return anything in 'res' just got blocked at curl_easy_perform. CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST set to "POST" works too and it returned the correct response. Many thanks!